# Repo manifest for different relative paths for git and review

Tags: git, repo

Is there any way to configure repo if there are different relative path for fetch and review.

Example

```
Fetch managed by gitweb : ssh://gitweb.foo.com/data/bar/foo.git
Review managed by gerrit : https://gerrit.foo.com:8081/review/bar/foo
```

With below manifest entries, fetch / sync works fine but `repo upload` fails as it looks up for `https://gerrit.foo.com:8081/data/bar/foo.git` and not `'https://gerrit.foo.com:8081/review/bar/foo.git'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <manifest>
    <remote name="repo_name" fetch="ssh://gitweb.foo.com/" review="https://gerrit.foo.com:8081" />
    <project path="code/foo" name="data/bar/foo" remote="repo_name" />
  </manifest>
```

What would be the right way to point gerrit review with a path, in repo manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

`<project path="code/foo" name="data/bar/foo" remote="repo_name" />`

For manifest file of repo, the `path` attribute of `project` element is used to specify the folder where the project will be clone to, i.e your worktree folder, the `name` attribute will be appended to remote url for specifying the remote repository. It seems you mix the usage of path attribute and name atribute in project element.

You can refer [manifest-format](https://git-repo.info/en/docs/multi-repos/manifest-format/) for more details of manifest file.

Comment: Well, my problem is related to review (repo upload). With above manifest `repo upload` looks for "https://gerrit.foo.com/data/bar/foo.git" I want it to point it to "https://gerrit.foo.com:8081/review/bar/foo"

Comment: P.S. links for git repo are review are different.

Comment: @Kamath, As I write in answer, you specified a wrong URL in manifest file for repo upload.

Answer (score 0):

for my project, not same as yours, but maybe help you

make an example:
my manifests.xml:
`review=http://192.168.100.100:8081`

one of my project fetch url = `http://192.168.100.100:8081/nathan/zhao/xxx/yyy/zzz`

so when using repo upload :
`repo upload xxx/yyy/zzz`
will push to `http://192.168.100.100:8081/xxx/yyy/zzz`

and 2 methods to fix this

first one: not using any relate path to your project, for example when create your project , change  `nathan/zhao/xxx/yyy/zzz` to `xxx/yyy/zzz`

second one: using ssh path(this one is WORKING for my gerrit server):
`review="ssh://192.168.100.100:29418/nathan/zhao"`

and then using repo upload
full url will be `ssh://192.168.100.100:29418/nathan/zhao/xxx/yyy/zzz`